# Combining Jasmine (Unit Tests) and Cypress (E2E Tests)?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, cypress, e2e-testing

We already use Jasmine for unit tests for our Angular app. Now, for end-to-end tests we are looking into Cypress, because it seems to be the best choice for e2e.

**Questions:**

1. Does it make sense to combine Unit Tests and E2E-Tests in general (regardless of which tool is used) *or is the idea that you do EITHER unit tests OR e2e tests*?
2. Does it make sense to (automatically) run unit tests with *Jasmine* and E2E tests with *Cypress* afterwards (instead of using protractor which will be soon unsupported)?

Comment: By combine do you mean first run your unit tests and then your end to end cypress tests? If that is the case, for CI, yes that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question accordingly - I'm interested in generally combining unit tests with e2e tests and also tool wise. You are welcomed to post your comment as official answer.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by combine, but given the topic you should look at [cypress-angular-unit-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-angular-unit-test).

Comment: WRT to either/or, I find that unit tests are quicker than Cypress tests, but perhaps that's because I only use Cypress for browser-based tests. On the other hand, Cypress e2e tests cover more code than unit tests, so less overall work by starting with Cypress.

Comment: For me #2 makes sense but for #1, I would keep unit tests separate from E2E tests.

Comment: @AliF50 OK, but are E2E tests in general a useful *addition* to unit tests, or is meant to only use *either* unit tests *or* E2E tests?

Comment: @Sarah Thanks, I updated question #1 accordingly, hope now it's clear what I mean?

Comment: It depends on your philosophy :). This is my opinion: no tests => bad. Some unit tests => good. Good quality unit and E2E tests => Excellent. https://3fxtqy18kygf3on3bu39kh93-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/test-automation-pyramid.jpg Check out that image. Since E2E's are more time consuming, you should ideally have less. So in conclusion, you can do neither, you can do either, or you can do both (preferable in my opinion). It all makes sense.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, @AliF50 - if you post this as an official answer I will mark it as such

Comment: Ok, thank you. In my answer I have linked a resource that I have found recently. I haven't read it all but it seems to be well written and it will answer this question you asked in even more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your philosophy :). This is my opinion: no tests => bad. Some unit tests => good. Good quality unit and E2E tests => Excellent. 3fxtqy18kygf3on3bu39kh93-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/… Check out that image. Since E2E's are more time consuming, you should ideally have less. So in conclusion, you can do neither, you can do either, or you can do both (preferable in my opinion). It all makes sense.

As a bonus, I have stumbled upon this resource. Very well written and it should answer all of your questions if you read through it.
https://testing-angular.com/